# Naming jQuery Functions

Tags: jquery, function

```
$(".song").live('click', function songClick() {
    //do stuff
});
```

Can you name a function like above and then call it at a later point?  I tried, but it didn't work.  Do I have to pass an event to it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just name it as a standalone function and call it from `live()`:

```
function songClick() {
  // do stuff
}

$(".song").live('click', songClick);
```

Note the lack of parens in the `live()` method.

Answer (score 11):

Note for reference's sake:

The live method was removed in version 9. Anyone coming across this question now should use on() instead. But otherwise, should work the same as above answers.

```
function songClick() {
//code
}

$(".song").on('Click', songClick);
```

If you only want the event handler to run once you can also use one() as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can define the function *before* the jquery code, then just pass the name to jquery; i.e.,

```
function songClick() {
    //do stuff
}
$(".song").live('click', songClick);
```

You could then use songClick() elsewhere, too.